# In ADB Shell, PIO is not picking up I2C device

Tags: adb, gpio, i2c, android-things, magnetometer

ADB PIO is not picking up an I2C device (HMC5883L Magnetometer).

I have the magnetometer connected correctly to VCC, GND, SDA & SCL.  Then within `adb shell` I use `pio i2c I2C1 0x3D read-raw 1` and it's giving me `[WARNING:client_errors.cc(35)] error 6: No such device or address`

I am wondering what I'm missing, any help would be appreciated!

```
Stats:
Android-Things
NXP i.MX7d on PICO-Pi
HMC5883L 3 Axis Magnetometer on I2C
Android Studio - Command Line ADB
```

Comment: I'd verify that your device is connected to the I2C bus and that you're sending the correct address.

Comment: It's physically connected (wires to pins), and I have the correct address according the manufacturers spec ( 0x3D ).  Is there another way to test if its' connected to the bus?

Comment: Is there a command to list all devices connected to I2C bus?

Comment: By the nature of how I2C works, there's no auto-detect mode to know if a device is connected.

Comment: Do you know of any prewritten scripts that would do an address scan to see if any addresses responded?

Comment: I don't know of one off-hand, but you can find such scripts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have the magnetometer connected correctly to VCC, GND, SDA & SCL. Then within `adb shell` I use `pio i2c I2C1 0x3D read-raw 1` and it's giving me `[WARNING:client_errors.cc(35)] error 6: No such device or address`

There are potentially a couple things wrong with this command, according to the [HMC5883L datasheet](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/HMC5883L_3-Axis_Digital_Compass_IC.pdf):

1. The device uses register-based access which means a raw read is likely to fail. You should be using a command like `read-reg-byte` to test communication with the device.
2. The I2C device address is `0x1E`. The datasheet gives you the completed 8-bit format of the address in a full byte (which is `0x3D` and `0x3C`, depending on the R/W bit), which is a bit confusing.

So a better command for you to send and test your device would be this one, which should report the value of the `STATUS` register:

```
$ pio i2c I2C1 0x1E read-reg-byte 0x09
```

If you still receive the same error with the above command, check the [pinout diagram](https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/imx7d#io-pinout) to verify you are connected to the right I2C port (I2C1 vs. I2C2).

Comment: You solved it, thank you.  It returned a hex value for the reg.  I was interpreting the specs incorrectly.  So, does android then add a read/write flag automatically in the read-reg-byte command in pio?

Also, I know that you took time out of your day to solve that.  Much appreciated.

Comment: Yes, R/W bits are set appropriately by the API, but moreso commands like read-reg-* are a special type of command because it's actually a write (with the register address) followed by a read. Many register-based devices don't know what to do with a raw read because they expect the register address to be written first.

Comment: It's unfortunate if this tool doesn't offer a simple probe as would be used in a scan; even if a *data* response would not be triggered without a valid register access, the I2C peripheral still must ack the address word before anything further like a register access can be sent, and that is how something like linux i2c-detect can work.